# Windows 10 - explorer.exe repeatedly restarting after update to 20H2 - flashing taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, crash, flashing

upon login my taskbar flashes for about 2 minutes before then starting properly. It appears to be explorer.exe repeatedly crashing.

After looking at the dmp it's crashing with callstack:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF937C2286E (ucrtbase.dll) in explorer.exe.2824.dmp: Fatal program exit requested. 


>   ucrtbase.dll!abort()   Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!terminate()   Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!FindHandler<__FrameHandler4>() Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!__InternalCxxFrameHandler<class __FrameHandler4>(struct EHExceptionRecord *,unsigned __int64 *,struct _CONTEXT *,struct _xDISPATCHER_CONTEXT *,struct FH4::FuncInfo4 *,int,unsigned __int64 *,unsigned char)   Unknown
    ucrtbase.dll!__CxxFrameHandler4()  Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!__GSHandlerCheck_EH4()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlRaiseException()  Unknown
    [External Code] 
    twinui.pcshell.dll!wil::details::ThrowPlatformException(struct wil::FailureInfo const &,wchar_t const *)    Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!wil::details::ReportFailure()    Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!wil::details::ReportFailure_Hr(void *,unsigned int,char const *,char const *,char const *,void *,enum wil::FailureType,long) Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!wil::details::in1diag3::Throw_Hr(void *,unsigned int,char const *,long)  Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!WindowManagerBridge::RuntimeClassInitialize(struct IWindowEventDispatcherInternal *) Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Details::MakeAndInitialize<class WindowManagerBridge,struct IWindowManagerBridge,class WindowEventDispatcher *>(struct IWindowManagerBridge * *,class WindowEventDispatcher * &&)    Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!WindowEventDispatcher::RuntimeClassInitialize(void)  Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!Microsoft::WRL::Details::MakeAndInitialize<class WindowEventDispatcher,struct IUnknown>(struct IUnknown * *) Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!Microsoft::WRL::SimpleClassFactory<class WindowEventDispatcher,0>::CreateInstance(struct IUnknown *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)   Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!ImmersiveShellComponentCreator::CreateComponent(struct _GUID const &,struct _GUID const &,void * *)  Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!CImmersiveShellCreationBehavior::CreateComponentWithSxs(bool,struct IMMERSIVE_SHELL_COMPONENT const &,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown
    twinui.pcshell.dll!CImmersiveShellCreationBehavior::CreateComponent(unsigned int,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown
    windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovider.dll!CImmersiveShellController::CreateComponents()    Unknown
    windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovider.dll!CImmersiveShellController::ComponentsThreadProc()    Unknown
    windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovider.dll!<lambda>(void)() Unknown
    windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovider.dll!<lambda_83b4adb8b1f66e82d5773e4fa18ceb2a>::<lambda_invoker_cdecl>()  Unknown
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown
```

looking at it it seems like "twinui.pcshell.dll!WindowManagerBridge::RuntimeClassInitialize(struct IWindowEventDispatcherInternal *)" is throwing an exception here. Is there any clues as to what could be going on here or is this perhaps a known issue? twinui.pcshell.dll appears to be legitimate.

Comment: Run Reliability Monitor (Control Pane, Security and Maintenance, Maintenance).  There should be a number of stopped working errors. What are the errors?

Comment: Thanks John, repeated explorer.exe crashes in the form of:

`Description
Faulting Application Path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: BEX64
Application Name: explorer.exe
Application Version: 10.0.19041.1023
Application Timestamp: c438eef0
Fault Module Name: ucrtbase.dll
Fault Module Version: 10.0.19041.789
Fault Module Timestamp: 2bd748bf
Exception Offset: 000000000007286e
Exception Code: c0000409
Exception Data: 0000000000000007
OS Version: 10.0.19042.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID: 2057
... (snip due to char limit).

Comment: Indicating this started directly after the first boot since this was installed:
"Installation Successful: Windows successfully installed the following update: Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.339.1261.0)"

Comment: Then after many of these:
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.19041.964, time stamp: 0x8aeeaedf
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.19041.789, time stamp: 0x2bd748bf
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000007286e
Faulting process ID: 0x2568
Faulting application start time: 0x01d74fd6cf28fa4d
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report ID: 28ffaf13-f323-401a-9800-6a19ed2fb1ca
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: You should try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Start with the option to keep everything but you may need to be more aggressive than that.